# Phonegap 3.1 on iOS hide splash screen manually

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I have the following in my config.xml file:

```
<preference name="splashscreen" value="splash" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="fade-splash-screen-duration" value="5000" />
<preference name="splash-screen-duration" value="5000" />

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />

<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen"/>
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
```

and on initializing my app I have the following:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
}, 2500);
```

I've also installed the splash screen plugin using the instructions found [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html)

despite this the splash screen is not delayed and instead a white screen flashes before my app loads. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the app in debug with xcode? Are there any messages output?

I've had this issue before and got a warning saying "The splashscreen image named Default-Portrait was not found"

My splash screen was named something else, so I created another called "Default-Portrait" and added it to the project.

Same goes for the @2x version.